# Android vs. Maven Internal Repositories

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Say I need to use some proprietary jars in my android library. I want my library to be conveniently available from Maven Central, but I can't just put dependencies there due to legal issues.

I figured it's possible to use [Internal Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) to host dependencies so they would be resolved automatically.

I've used Github repo, just like [this one](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), and declared it in library `pom.xml`

However Gradle doesn't seem to be resolving this dependencies. If I manually declare my repository in main `build.gradle` everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong here, or android gradle plugind just don't support internal repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's discouraged in the Maven community to have repository declarations in published POMs, and Gradle won't honor them. Instead, downstream builds will have to declare the internal repository in one way or another (which shouldn't be a big deal).

If you (only) publish POMs for proprietary dependencies to Maven Central (which is a common solution to this problem at least if you own the dependencies), downstream builds will need to declare the internal repository as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        artifactUrls "https://some.internal.repo"
    }
}
```

If you don't publish proprietary dependencies to Maven Central at all (not even POMs), downstream builds will have to declare the internal repository as another regular Maven repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://some.internal.repo"
    }
}
```

Note however that last time I checked, one of the rules of publishing to Maven Central was that dependencies needed to be available from Maven Central as well.

PS: Whether you are publishing a Java or Android library shouldn't matter here.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll stick to manually declared maven repo for now.